# UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW too soon

Tags: apex, exception, locking

According to Salesforce's [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000338933&type=1) a transaction can wait for up to 10 seconds before throwing an exception with the code "UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW". Yet I get the following scenario:

1. Transaction A begins on object "CustomObject__c" and locks the Master "Contact" record (The execution time is > 5 seconds).
2. Transaction B begins on object "CustomObject__c" few milliseconds after transaction A began and waits ~3 seconds for the lock on the same master "Contact" record to be released before throwing a DmlExecutionException with the code "UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW".

**Why does Transaction B wait for so little time instead of the documented 10 seconds?**

*Note 1: There was no execution of any operation in the ORG for few minutes before Transaction A.*

*Note 2: The scenario is executed in a Sandbox.*

*Edit: Following the previous comments, I confirm that no process was running on the background (Confirmed by a SOQL on AsyncApexJob object.*

Comment: no batch jobs or managed package operations running while Transaction B executes?

Comment: +1 to prev comment, you probably have something else going on. If you are sure it's just two transactions, please edit your question and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Is that supposed to have an impact? Shouldn't Transaction B wait for the full 10 seconds regardless of what's running on the background?

Comment: Back in 2013, one of my early answers [saw the timeout after 4-5 seconds](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/22640/2984), but later, I confirmed that it did get "about" ten seconds. I ran the code again with some modification to output the wait time, and I rather consistently got about 9980ms of transaction time before timing out. I would hypothesize that it may be because of too much contention in the database?

Comment: I did a profiling on Transaction B, the execution time is around 5 seconds (3 of which is idle waiting for the lock).

Comment: EXECUTION_STARTED timestamp is around ~5000000 (5ms) and EXECUTION_FINISHED timestamp is around ~5300000000 (5.3 seconds) so the lock is clearly not maintained for 10 seconds.

Comment: @alozzi We don't see your logs and we don't have access to your org.  If you believe this is a bug or it's not working as advertised, then open a case with SF support.